# select two table different fields in single column?

Tags: php, mysql, join, union

i Need to join two table columns with different fields in a single column

Table1 like this

```
id1        Name1        class1
1          aaa          CS
2          bbb          MBA
3          ccc          MCA
```

Another table fileds as table2

```
id2         name2         class2
1           ddd           CS
2           eee           MBA
3           fff           MCA
```

I want to select both the table into sinlge result as

Result :

```
id2         name2         class2
1           aaa           CS
2           bbb           MBA
3           ccc           MCA   
1           ddd           CS
2           eee           MBA
3           fff           MCA
```

Answer (score 2):

`UNION ALL` is all you need. It also keeps duplicates.

```
SELECT ID1 ID, Name1 Name, Class1 Class FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID2 ID, Name2 Name, Class2 Class FROM Table2
```

If you want to have the result unique, remove `ALL`,

```
SELECT ID1 ID, Name1 Name, Class1 Class FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT ID2 ID, Name2 Name, Class2 Class FROM Table2
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean innerjoin?

For instance:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2  ON Table.Class1 = Table2.Cat_ID 
    INNER JOIN tbl_Klant   ON tbl_Project.KlantID
```

Or what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` or `UNION`.
The difference between UNION and UNION ALL is that Union all will not eliminate duplicate rows, instead it just pulls all rows from all tables fitting your query specifics and combines them into a table.

`UNION` works like `Select Distinct` on resultset obtained from both the tables.
For retrieving all the rows from both the tables do `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT ID1 ID, Name1 Name, Class1 Class FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID2 ID, Name2 Name, Class2 Class FROM Table2
```

or for unique rows

```
SELECT ID1 ID, Name1 Name, Class1 Class FROM Table1
UNION 
SELECT ID2 ID, Name2 Name, Class2 Class FROM Table2
```